# MVC 5 with backend EF6 Code First System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'Domain\xxxxxxxx'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having issue with DB connection where my MVC 5 EF6 Code first application is trying to connect to my Microsoft SQL Server that reside in a different server.

here is my error:

`Login failed for user 'Domain\xxxxxxxx'.`

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

`Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'Domain\xxxxxxxx'.`

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'Domain\xxxxxxxx'.]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +414
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +167
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +83
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +360
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32() +426
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? Does that user exist in the database?

Comment: Domain User xxxxxxxx needs rights to that SQL Server. Make sure it works in SSMS first.

Comment: On a local box it works fine but not when it is deployed to it's own server. Local and the web server access the same DB server.

Comment: Right, because when you run off the web server it is no longer using your domain account. Whatever the user name is in the message needs to be given access on the SQL Server for the database in question. Over here our DBA creates domain accounts for each application and does the database mapping. Another option is to use SQL Authentication and a connection string with user id and password.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check your `connectionString` in the `web.config` is the username and password correct?

Also I met a similar problem when i was using migrations. I was running my project on a Windows 10 Insider Preview (dont remeber the build) and it was a PowerShell issue

Comment: Thank you Steve Green for you help.